# Elastic update by query with synonym search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using synonyms (defined in a file) in my mapping, and the searches work very well. I am now trying to update a field in the document using update_by_query with a synonym search, with no luck.

Here is an analogy for what I'm trying to do:

1. Synonyms are :

   ```
   dog => max, rex, lassie, foster
   cat => shadow, cricket, ruby
   ```
2. Example document

   ```
   {
     "type": "unknown",
     "names" : "simba, foster, lassie, ruby",
     "tricks": "yes"
   }
   ```

If I do a search for a dog or a cat, this document will show up.

I'm trying to use update by query, so that if the query is for `dog`,
the type will be updated to `dog`. Or similarly, if the query is for `cat`, the type will be updated to `dog, cat`.

Is this possible with update by query, or should I do something else?
The ultimate goal is to have all docs with type as `unknown` to be replaced with the actual type. The data is then exported to another tool.

Comment: Can you show your mapping and current query?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.
Update by query is now working, as expected. It was a problem in the "painless" script and also the query terms.